# SONY XDCAM Cant open files on macbook

Tags: video-editor, final-cut-pro-x, file-formats, mac, sony

I can't open the BPAV folder on my mac, not in quicktime or in Final cut pro. I don't know why can anybody help?
[image: this is what i'm seeing]

Comment: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202252 ?

Comment: @aud Fancy making that into an answer?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that you haven't installed needed additional software as is mentioned in the Apple's support page [Import Sony XAVC and XDCAM media in Final Cut Pro](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202252).

> You need to install additional software to import Sony XAVC and XDCAM
> media.

As of January 2023, there are two options depending on the Final Cut Pro version you're running, one of which (for FCP version 10.1.4 or earlier) requires installing Sony software.